# Sweet alert shows TRUE instead of alert text

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert

I'm working with Sweet Alert to show some message so I coded this:

```js
$(document).on('click', '#rules', function(e) {
  swal({
    html: true,
    title: '<b>Title</b>',
    text: '<b>Text</b>'
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>

<button id="rules">Rules</button>
```

But it shows this:

[image]

However it should be written **Text** as `text`!

So what's going wrong here? How can I solve this issue?

Comment: What do you think `html: true` means?

Comment: What version of sweetalert do you have?

Comment: @Barmar I thought `html:true` means that it accepts *html* data as well! So what's the point of `text` property here if we can simply define our data in `html`?

Comment: @User456 `swal` is for version 1

Comment: You can either provide HTML or plain text. If you provide both, it uses the HTML.

Comment: _"what's the point"_... because `text` is sanitised / escaped whereas `html` is not

Comment: You're apparently using Sweet Alert 2, because version 1 doesn't have the `html` option.

Comment: @Barmar Swal.fire is for version 2

Comment: @Barmar It is v1. The `html` property is [deprecated](https://github.com/t4t5/sweetalert/blob/master/src/modules/options/deprecations.ts#L99) in favour of `content`. I assume they do the same thing though

Comment: @nagidi exactly what documentation where you following that lead you to use the `html` property? It's not in the current docs so why use it?

Comment: I've just made your code into a runnable snippet. Did you not see the console warning about the `html` option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`html` is not a boolean option, it's a string of HTML. And in `v1` it has been deprecated in favor of `content`.

So you should write

```
$(document).on('click', '#rules', function(e) {
     swal({ title:'<b>Title</b>', content:'<b>Text</b>'});
});
```

Comment: Doesn't appear to work (based on the snippet in the question)